Window Function LEAD not next
I have a Stock movement situation in DATABRICKS, where I have a row for a Production ENTER and another row for product CANCEL.



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY




1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 12:00
10


2
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 12:10
10


3
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
30


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:10
30


5
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:40
30


6
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:50
40



I need to associate the CANCEL_MOVEMENT_ID to a ENTER, so I can identify it as canceled.
The only way to know what's the respective CANCEL is by DATE_TIME. I'm trying to usi Window lead function, the problem is that sometime I can have 2(or more) CANCEL after the two ENTER (example the IDs from 3 to 6). In this case I need to associate the first ENTER for first CANCEL and so on (3-5 and 4-6).
The result should be the example below.



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY
CANCEL_MOVEMENT




1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 12:00
10
2


2
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 12:10
10



3
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
30
5


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:10
30
6


5
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:40
30



6
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:50
40




The query I'm trying to use is this one, but it always get the previous row.
SELECT a.*,
LEAD(a.MOVEMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY a.PRODUCT ORDER BY a.DATE_TIME) AS CANCEL_MOVEMENT
FROM table_movement a

Any Idea?
If that's not clear, let me know, I can give more explanations.

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Inzzwchq

Try using Row_Number to give each Enter/Cancel a seq number. then match them up

Do the enter and cancel movements always come in neat pairs? An example that violates this might be: enter, cancel, cancel, enter, enter, cancel, cancel. Also do the quantities ever come into play?

This solution uses a CTE and a self join.
WITH CTE as
(  
SELECT a.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MOVEMENT_TYPE ORDER BY Movement ASC) as rn
FROM   table_movement a
)
SELECT t.*,
    cancel.Movement as CANCEL_MOVEMENT
FROM CTE t
LEFT JOIN CTE cancel ON cancel.rn=t.rn and t.MOVEMENT_TYPE='ENTER' and cancel.MOVEMENT_TYPE='CANCEL'
ORDER BY t.Movement

fiddle



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY
rn
CANCEL_MOVEMENT




1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 12:00
10
1
2


2
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 12:10
10
1
null


3
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
30
2
5


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:10
30
3
6


5
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:40
30
2
null


6
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:50
40
3
null




This solution better matches your attempt, avoids a self join, and might have better performance.
WITH CTE as
(  
SELECT a.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MOVEMENT_TYPE ORDER BY Movement ASC) as rn
FROM   table_movement a
)
SELECT t.*,
    LEAD(t.MOVEMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY t.rn ORDER BY t.DATE_TIME) AS CANCEL_MOVEMENT2
FROM CTE t
ORDER BY t.Movement

fiddle
